Can't replace TextView among FrameLayouts
I was trying to replace TextView among the fragments, which are placed in FrameLayouts. So the TextView is seen in the design, but isn't seen in app on virtual device.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="385dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".RegistrationContainerFragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/auth_container_background"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:translationZ="4dp"
android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/username_and_email_input_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/password_input_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/primary_button_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold_font"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:text="Forgot password?"/>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/textAndLinkText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>

import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.InputType
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction


class LoginContainerFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration_container, container, false)

        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = childFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        val title = TitleFragment()
        title.setShowBackArrow(true)
        title.setTitleText("Log In")
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.title, title)

        val textInputFragment = InputFragment()
        textInputFragment.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
        textInputFragment.setInputHint("Enter your email or username")
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.text_input_container, textInputFragment)

        val passwordInputFragment = InputFragment()
        passwordInputFragment.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
        passwordInputFragment.setInputHint("Enter your password")
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.password_input_container, passwordInputFragment)

        val primaryButtonFragment = PrimaryButtonFragment()
        primaryButtonFragment.setButtonText("next")
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.primary_button_container, primaryButtonFragment)

        val lineFragment = LineFragment()
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.line, lineFragment)

        val textAndLinkFragment = TextWithLinkFragment()
        textAndLinkFragment.setTextAndLinkText(
            getString(R.string.dont_have_an_account),
            getString(R.string.sign_in)
        )
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.textAndLinkText, textAndLinkFragment)

        fragmentTransaction.commit()

        return view
    }

}

I was trying to place the TextView within FrameLayout, it didn't help.
After that I was trying to make a fragment for this TextView, but somehow my app wasn't launching and was instead crashing.
Also I was trying to use some tags like \<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout\>, but it didn't help.

text_input_container is used but it doesn't exist in your layout
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.text_input_container, textInputFragment)

